# identify the type of cactus

Tags: identification, cactus

My friend showed me this picture of a cactus and we would like to buy one. The problem is we don't know the name.

Does anybody recognize it? Does it produce flowers?

[image]

Comment: Hi Roj! I just found this old question, and am wondering what happened to this plant. Did it produce the flowers that would have been expected by the identification in the answer here? Would you care to update us so we can see if it might have been a different type of cactus? Thanks!

Comment: yes it produced yellow flowers 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be a young [Mammillaria longimamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammillaria_longimamma), which can produce yellow flowers.